# ReaderWriterLockSlim and Pulse/Wait

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there an equivalent of `Monitor.Pulse` and `Monitor.Wait` that I can use in conjunction with a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`?

I have a class where I've encapsulated multi-threaded access to an underlying queue. To enqueue something, I acquire a lock that protects the underlying queue (and a couple of other objects) then add the item and `Monitor.Pulse` the locked object to signal that something was added to the queue.

```
public void Enqueue(ITask task)
{
    lock (mutex)
    {
        underlying.Enqueue(task);
        Monitor.Pulse(mutex);
    }
}
```

On the other end of the queue, I have a single background thread that continuously processes messages as they arrive on the queue. It uses `Monitor.Wait` when there are no items in the queue, to avoid unnecessary polling. (I consider this to be good design, but any flames (within reason) are welcome if they help me learn otherwise.)

```
private void DequeueForProcessing(object state)
{
    while (true)
    {
        ITask task;
        lock (mutex)
        {
            while (underlying.Count == 0)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(mutex);
            }
            task = underlying.Dequeue();
        }
        Process(task);
    }
}
```

As more operations are added to this class (requiring read-only access to the lock protected underlying), someone suggested using `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. I've never used the class before, and assuming it can offer some performance benefit, I'm not against it, but only if I can keep the Pulse/Wait design.

Comment: For feedback... I wouldn't personally assume that waking from `Wait` means "there's data"; I would hit `continue;` and check it again. This approach makes it easier to add a stop/drain facility later. You also might want to only `Pulse` if you've added to a previously-empty queue; otherwise, nothing is waiting.

Comment: I like the idea of doing the pulse only after adding a single item to the queue. However, I have a bunch of other doubts about my code (as well I should, it's multi-threaded,) as well as the efficiency of counting the items in the queue and comparing that value with 0 (I hope it doesn't walk a linked list to do the counting.) I guess I should really call PulseAll in case it's another writer thread that recieves the single pulse.

Comment: I'd agree with the `PulseAll`. Re the `Count`, see documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy0wwyz4.aspx "Retrieving the value of this property is an O(1) operation."; meaning: no, it doesn't do that - it knows the `Count` separately.

Comment: That's good to know, but something to watch out for if I ever needed to inject a different queue implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit (and after accepting Mark's challenge (I agree, my change isn't exactly basic)) I came up with this combination:

```
ReaderWriterLockSlim rwls;
AutoResetEvent are;
```

```
public void Enqueue(ITask task) {
    rwls.EnterWriteLock();
    try {
        underlying.Enqueue(task);
        if (underlying.Count == 1) {
          are.Set();
        }
    } finally {
        rwls.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

```
private void DequeueForProcessing(object state) {
    while (true) {
        ITask task;
        rwls.EnterWriteLock();
        try {
            while (underlying.Count == 0) {
                rwls.ExitWriteLock();
                are.WaitOne();
                rwls.EnterWriteLock();
            }
            task = underlying.Dequeue();
        } finally {
            rwls.ExitWriteLock();
        }
        Process(task);
    }
}
```

To my untrained eye, it seems to fit the bill (though it's a little uglier, to be sure,) and it's not too different from the original version.

Answer (score 1):

No, basically. It is optimised to provide some specific/common scenarios. If you go outside those scenarios it won't work. If you need `Pulse` etc, use `Monitor` instead.

Comment: Are there any other built-in .NET mechanisms that can put the current thread back into the waiting queue for a lock, or is that what a monitor <i>does</i>?